# Close splash screen in Hololens 2 with unity

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I am a new in Hololens 2 and I build some Unity sample on it.
When start application, it would placed a white box like that.
[image]
When stop application, the white box still on here and I need to click X to close it.
I have searched about that, it seem like about uwp application lifecycle?
Is there any method to close it with C# when I quit my application.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by design and can only be closed manually, every app starts in mixed reality by placing an app tile in the Windows Mixed Reality home and these tiles persist and stay at their placed location. For more information please see:[App model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-model)

In addition to this, you can add a custom holographic splash screen for the app, please refer to this link:[Holographic splash screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/recommended-settings-for-unity#holographic-splash-screen)