# HoloLens App Going Black After 1-2 Minutes of Operation

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, crash, hololens

I opened an application that I developed by Unity in HoloLens, but the application only lasted for 1-2 minutes each time, then it went black. The black screen lasted for about 10 seconds, then a pop-up window appeared. The pop-up window showed a cross in the center, as shown in the picture([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3g6m.jpg)). I tried various methods to solve it, but none of them worked, so I came here for help.

I referred to the solution mentioned in this question ([Close splash screen in Hololens 2 with unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178732/close-splash-screen-in-hololens-2-with-unity))

(It is by design and can only be closed manually, every app starts in mixed reality by placing an app tile in the Windows Mixed Reality home and these tiles persist and stay at their placed location. For more information please see: App model

In addition to this, you can add a custom holographic splash screen for the app, please refer to this link: Holographic splash screen),

but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you looked into the [log file (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<productname>\TempState\UnityPlayer.log`)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html)